# Trying to get property 'message' of non-object laravel message

Tags: laravel

Trying to get property 'message' of non-object

```
@foreach($myNotifications as $myNotifications)
@php
/** @var \App\Models\Notification\Notification $myNotifications */
@endphp
<?php echo e($myNotifications->data->message); ?>
@endforeach
```

with database structure field data:

```
{"message":"sisa stock Galon merek madinah tersisa 4","status":"Urgent","url":"link"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that "data" is encoded json string. You can cast data field to array in model and that will make data->message work.

Add this to Notification model:

```
protected $casts = [
    'data' => 'array',
];
```

See [Array & JSON Casting](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting)